# TypeError: Cannot read property 'item_name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, typeerror, npm-start

I'm a beginner level for React js and I'm trying to create todo app. basically there's one text input here. my app run perfectly when I run " npm start" and show my expected output on my port. but when I add something for my list it's doesn't add anything and show this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'newItem' of undefined" error.

here is my code..

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          newItem:"",
          list:[]
        }

      }

      updateInput(key, value){
          //update react state
          this.setState(
            {
                [key]:value
            }
          );
      }

      addItem(){

        //crete item with unique id
        const newItem = {
          id: 1 + Math.random(),                        //error here
          value: this.value.newItem.slice()
        };

        //copy of current list of item
        const list = [...this.state.list];

        //add new item to list
        list.push(newItem);

        //update item with new list and reset newitem input
        this.setState(
          {
            list,
            newItem:""
          }
        );
      }

      deleteItem(id){

        //copy current list of item
        const list = {...this.state.list};

        //filter out item being deleted
        const updatedList = list.filter( item => item.id !== id);

        this.setState({
          list: updatedList
        });
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <div className="App">
            <div>
                Add an items...
                <br/>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Add your task.."
                  value={this.state.newItem}
                  onChange={e=> this.updateInput("newItem", e.target.value)}
                />

                <button
                  onClick={()=> this.addItem()}                     //error here
                >
                  Add
                </button>

                <br/>
                <ul>
                  {this.state.list.map( item=>{
                    return(
                      <li key={item.id}>
                        {item.value}
                        <button 
                         onClick={()=> this.deleteItem(item.id)}
                        >X</button>
                      </li>
                    )
                  })}
                 
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default App;
```

Chrome browser console shows error like **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'newItem' of undefined**
I've noted my error lines as comments //error.

Comment: `this.value.newItem.slice()` this should be `this.state.newItem`

Comment: this was a some issues in my code and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Change `value: this.value.newItem.slice()` in your code to `this.state.newItem.slice()`, this fixes the error which is occuring on the addItem() method. As there is no attribute as value for the class App, this causes the undefined error.

And change `const list = {...this.state.list};` to `const list = [...this.state.list];` in the deleteItem() method, which also causes an error while trying to delete a todo.

Kindly do upvote the solution, if you find it helpful.

Comment: now it's working properly. thank you for the correct answer.